# How to use gwt-dispatch with its CachingDispatchAsync (GWT, GWTP)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I found a link http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/tips-for-using-cachingdispatchasync-with-gwt-dispatch/

But there is no step by step guideline for how to use it.

I am using GWTP (with Gwt2.5).

So Can you provide a very simple example how to use gwt-dispatch with its CachingDispatchAsync?

Comment: see http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/08/google-web-toolkit-gwt-mvp-example.html

Comment: do u have a simpler example?

Comment: see this also: http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/caching-batching-dispatcher-for-gwt-dispatch/